# Why am I getting syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end with scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm a beginner, and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 10 weeks now. When trying to run an RSpec test on one of my models, I get this error:

rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

It looks like my brackets are closed and I have ended properly.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  scope :created_after, -> (7.days.ago) { where("item.created_at > ?", 7.days.ago) }

 end
```

The purpose of the scope is to be able to differentiate items that are older than 7 days from  items written in the last week.

Here is my schema for this the list model:

```
  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "body"
    t.integer  "list_id"
    t.boolean  "done",       default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end`
```

I've looked at the Rails Guides and have searched repeatedly but can't find anything that tells me my current syntax is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose/intended meaning of the `(7.days.ago)` lambda parameter?

Comment: with "where" I'm looking for items that were created 7 days ago or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with how you have defined your lambda. As you just started learning Ruby & Rails I would recommend you read [this article](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/34-lambdas-and-blocks-in-ruby/lessons/77-lambdas-in-ruby) to understand what lambdas are, how they operate and what the syntax is. The code in round brackets should be a variable name that can be passed into the lambda rather than a definition of a date. E.g your code:

```
scope :created_after, -> (7.days.ago) { where("item.created_at > ?", 7.days.ago) }
```

Should be:

```
scope :created_after, -> (date) { where("item.created_at > ?", date) }
```

That way you can create queries on `Items` like this:

```
new_items = Item.created_after(7.days.ago) # or..
newer_items = Item.created_after(3.days.ago) # or...
new_done_items = Item.where(done: true).created_after(7.days.ago) # etc
```